# Filtering on a ProjectToList in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, automapper, mediatr

I am using MediatR to request A visualizationDto

```
public VisualizationResponse Handle(VisualizationQuery message)
{
    return new VisualizationResponse
    {
        LoadTick = DateTime.Now.Ticks,
        Visualization = new VisualizationDto
        {
            infeed = context.Unloaders.ProjectToList<InfeedDto>(),
            Levels = context.Levels.ProjectToList<LevelDto>()
        }
    };
}
```

These get mapped directly from a `DbContext`. Now the problem is that `ProjectToList<>` maps recursively. In the level there's a list of buffers and in each buffer there's a list of stacks. Now i only need to map the stacks that have a TimeOut value of null. I don't want to filter trough everything after mapping because this might slow down things. And i tried

```
var lq = context.Levels;
var stacks = lq
    .SelectMany(l => l.Buffers)
    .SelectMany(b => b.StackLocations)
    .Where(s => s.TimeOut == null);

Levels = lq.ProjectTo<LevelDto>().Select(l => new {l, stacks}).ToList().Select(x => x.l).ToList()
```

But the values i receive aren't the filtered ones still the full dataset. Are there any other ways to filter on a `ProjectToList`?

right now i have an output that looks like

```
List<LevelDto>
-List<BufferDto>
  -List<StackLocationDto>
    -stack timeIn- TimeOut
    -stack timeIn- TimeOut
    -stack timeIn- null
    -stack timeIn- null
```

i need to filter out the stacks that are already finished so those that do not have a TimeOut of null.

Comment: What does the code for ProjectTo look like?  What is the expected output, and what is the output you are actually getting?

Comment: ProjectTo is an automapper function. It maps objects that are similar so a level and levelDto have the same properties instead of writing a lot of unneeded code to map 1 to the other this does it with a single function

Answer (score 0):

The Where condition is only executed to stacks not to lq. Try `stacks.ProjectTo<LevelDto>()`, that should do the trick.

Comment: i use ProjectTo to map between db entities and dto's so stacks to stackdto's and level to leveldto's. that's why i mapped the lq and added the filtered stacks later using .Select(l => new {l, stacks}).ToList().Select(x => x.l).ToList() but i'll see if i can find a way to build the level from the stacks up though

Comment: lq and stacks seems to be IQuerable. If you use `Where` you don't apply this to lq. It creates a new Query and lq is the same as before. You can try `lq.Where(l => l.Buffers.Any(b => b.StackLocations.Any(s => s.TimeOut == null))).ProjectTo<LevelDto>()`

Comment: no that's the first thing i tried, the filter doesn't seem to get past projectTo. and if i filter afterwards it's already a list so large sets could be very slow.